# Trying to write a struct to a proc file from kernel space

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to write a structure to a `proc` file (I know I'm not suppose to).  I'm able to successfully write out the struct members using the `seq_print` method but I want to try writing the struct so I don't have to parse it in user space.  I'm not sure how to write to it using the `seq_file` implementation.  Below is the code I'm trying.  The `seq_show` function is part of my `.read,` file_operation struct callback mechanism (`file_operations`, `seq_file`, `.start`, `.next`, `.stop`, `.show`) when the `/proc/info` is opened from user space.

```
typedef struct tmp_t{
    int number;
    uint_32 info;
    char name[10];
} tmp_t;


static int seq_show(struct seq_file *s, void *v)
{
ssize_t proc_write;
mm_segment_t old_fs;
struct file *file;
loff_t offset = 0;

old_fs = get_fs();
set_fs(get_ds());
file = filp_open("/proc/info", O_WRONLY, 0777);
if(file){
      //tmp is a global pointer to the struct I want to write
      proc_write = vfs_write(file, tmp, sizeof(tmp_t), &offset);
      // I've also tried this using the v parameter
      //proc_write = vfs_write(file, tmp, sizeof(tmp_t), v);
      fput(file);
      printk(KERN_ALERT "proc_write: %zd.\n");
}
filp_close(file, NULL);
set_fs(old_fs);

return 0;
}

static void *info_start(struct seq_file *s, loff_t *pos)
{

}

static void *info_next(struct seq_file *s, void *v, loff_t *pos)
{

}

static void info_stop(struct seq_file *s, void *v)
{

}

static int open_info(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    return seq_open(file, &seq_ops_info);
}

static struct seq_operations seq_ops_info = {
    .start  = info_start,
    .next   = info_next,
    .stop   = info_stop,
    .show   = info_show,
};

static const struct file_operations fops_info = {
    .owner          = THIS_MODULE,
    .open           = open_info,
    .read           = seq_read,
    .llseek         = seq_lseek,
    .release        = seq_release,
 };

static int __init app_init(void)
{
info_file = proc_create("info", 0777, NULL, &fops_info);
}
```

The printk statement gives `proc_write: -5.` I have those structs stored in a link list so each iteration through the seq_file stuff I'd like to write the struct to the `/proc/info`.  I'm trying to work off of this [example](http://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/drivers/staging/lustre/lustre/libcfs/kernel_user_comm.c.html#74) that I found in the kernel source tree.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the correct offset? Looks like you try overwrite existing data and kernel does not let you do it.

Comment: Why do you think that you can *write* in the `.read` implementation?

Comment: The fundamental misunderstanding here seems to be that /proc entries aren't actually files - rather they are interfaces where the kernel supplies data *on demand* when userspace tries to read from something that looks like a file.  But there's no storage backing them which a kernel module can scribble into for userspace to later read.  If that is what you want, make a buffer to dump to and methods that supply data from it when userspace  wants to read.

Comment: ok i wasn't sure if i could do this i'll go back to using seq_print to the proc file to get my info to the user.

Answer (score 1):

As far, as I know, you can't create and write file in `/proc` that easily. Most likely, call to `filp_open()` has failed and you don't check it's return value properly. You have to check return value with `IS_ERR()` function.

But I should mention again that this idea seems wrong for me. If you want create an entry in `/proc` directory, consider using [standard way](http://tuxthink.blogspot.com/2011/02/creating-readwrite-proc-entry.html).

Comment: sorry I left that code out.  i just included.  i create the proc file in the traditional way.

Comment: That doesn't matter. Unless you provided read/write function for your proc file, there is no way to write data into it. Given that, you should just display your data through `read_proc` function of that proc file.